# Override select list form value with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form comprised of a select list and an input field.  I would like the select list value to be overwritten, regardless of what is selected, if the input box has a value.

It looks like

```
myMap={"asdf":1,"qwerty":2}

function checkInput(){
    desiredSel=$('#input_id').val();
    if(desiredSel){
        alert(desiredSel);
        if(myMap[desiredSel]){
            alert(myMap[desiredSel]);
            //This is where I'm lost
        }
    }
}

<form onSubmit=checkInput()>
<select name='myselect' id='select_id'>
  <option value=1>First</option>
  <option value=2>second</option>
</select>
<input name='myinput' id='input_id' />
</form>
```

At my comment is where I'm not clear how to override the value that gets sent for $(#select_id)

**Edit For Clarification:**

If myinput is empty then myselect gets submitted with what ever option is actually selected

If myinput has a value and it matches a key in myMap then myselect would be submitted with the myMap[myinput]  value as if it was actually selected on that option (regardless of what was actually selected).

Comment: Your goal in this is kind of confusing, with the `select` and text input. I'm not sure what the text input has to do with anything. Could you elaborate? Do you expect to map the `select` element's value to a property in `myMap`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be what are you looking for

```
$('#select_id').val(myMap[desiredSel]);
```

.val() can return or set a value but that is specified in https://jquery.com/

Further information once you perform validation function you can change all the values and submit by `return true;` or block submission by `return false;`